# Can __using__ insert at end of a module?

Tags: elixir

Lets say I have a module I'm making where pattern matching is the bulk of it's functionality, like a struct or fancy case statement; is there a way that `use Module` can insert a clause at the **bottom** of the Module its used on? The reason for this is to add, lets say, default clauses that would catch matches which fail against those declared.

For a contrived example:

```
defmodule NumberToNumber do
    use SwitchLib, default: 0
#   import SomeMacros

    opt 1, "one"
#   convert("one"), do: 1

    opt 2, "two"
    opt 3, "three"
    opt 4, "four"

    default 0            <-- Can this be procedurally generated?
#   convert(_), do: 0    <--     or this, for that matter,

end
```

Is this possible, or should I be going about this a different way? My back up plan is to quote in a `convert(_)` that attempts `__MODULE__.convert(arg)` itself and accounts for no match independently.

In any event, is the aforementioned method made possible by the compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

Callbacks such as `@before_compile` allow you to inject code into the module when its definition is complete.

Besides `@before_compile` there are other useful module attributes like `@on_definition` and `@after_compile`, which you can read more about in the [docs for the Module module](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Module.html).

All of these facilities can be used in tandem with `__using__` or vanilla macros to create dynamically generated code that permits for you to write a loop that creates `opt i` statements for arbitrary ranges of `i`. You can find useful information about macros and the compilation environment in the documentation for the [Macro module](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Macro.html) and [Macro.Env](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Macro.Env.html).